# What does util.generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object() function in keras do

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

In Keras library, `activattion.get()` calls `activattion.deserialize()` function which in turn calls `util.generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object()` function. Can someone explain what happens in `deserialize_keras_object()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one may read [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L119) `deserialize_keras_object` is responsible for creation of a `keras` object from:

- configuration dictionary - if one is available,
- name identifier if a provided one was available.

To understand second point image the following definition:

```
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

What you provide to `Activation` constructor is a `string`, not a `keras` object. In order to make this work - `deserialize_keras_object` looks up defined names and check if an object called `sigmoid` is defined and instantiates it.